# Make screen fill gridlayout

Tags: android, android-xml, android-gridlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="1"
    android:rowCount="3"
    android:verticalSpacing="1px" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/AlertBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:src="@drawable/mylocation" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/myLocationBtn"
        android:layout_width="306dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:src="@drawable/proximity" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:src="@drawable/title" />

</GridLayout>
```

I want to make these 3 items completely fill the scren and if is possible no white space between each item. I have been playing with the gridlayout but since it's new and I don't have much experience in programming, I can't get what I want.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why you don't use linear layout instead of GridLayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the modified xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnCount="1"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/AlertBtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/mylocation" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/myLocationBtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/proximity" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/title" />

</LinearLayout>
```

let me know.. what do you think

If you want to remove the button background add this to the ImageButton

```
android:background="@null"
```

after removing the background for the button set you own custom background color or image in the parent linearlayout like this

```
android:background="#DCDCDC"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `LinearLayout` it's easy..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/AlertBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/mylocation" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/myLocationBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/proximity" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/title" />

</LinearLayout>
```